# Use of "and" for multiple mutual recursive functions in Ocaml

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, ocaml, ml

So I have three functions in OCaml

```
let my_A = my_C
let my_B = my_A
let my_C = my_B
```

Function A calls function C. Function B calls function A. Function C calls function B.

I tried to use "and" to make them mutually recursive (so they can call each other), as in:

```
let my_A = my_C
and
my_B = my_A
and
my_C = my_B
```

but it says

> "unbound value my_C in line __"

It's basically saying "hey you can't call `my_C` in `my_A`" but I don't understand why? Am I not allowed to chain three functions together?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must say `let rec ... and ... and ...`. You don't have the `rec`.